# Trying to work off and input by the user to change a value

Tags: java

I am creating a small game-type program,
Firstly I'm asking the user to give his name,
Secondly, I'm asking the user to choose one of the spaceships,
Thirdly, I want the user to add 2 modification, to improve the stats...
Here is the problem, I want to change some values of the spaceship.
The problem is that I don't know how to determine the chosen spaceship and how to change its values. Example: The Heavy-type Armour is 90 right now​ if I add the Advanced Hull Armour modification, i want it to increase to 100

```
    public class Game {
    static void playerName() {
    System.out.println("What's your name?:");
    String name = Keyboard.readString();
    System.out.println("Okay,"+name+" it is!\n");   
    }


    static class StarShip {     
    String name;
    String armour;
    String attack;      
    String mobility;
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Hello Rookie! \n");
    playerName();

    System.out.println("Let's pick your first ship!\n");
    System.out.println("Choose one of these:");

    //insert ships here:
    StarShip ship1 = new StarShip();
    ship1.name = "Heavy-type";
    ship1.armour = "Armour=90";
    ship1.attack = "Firepower=50";
    ship1.mobility = "Mobility=40";


    StarShip ship2 = new StarShip();
    ship2.name = "Medium-type";
    ship2.armour = "Armour=60";
    ship2.attack = "Firepower=60";
    ship2.mobility = "Mobility=60";

    StarShip ship3 = new StarShip();
    ship3.name = "Light-type";
    ship3.armour = "Armour=20";
    ship3.attack = "Firepower=60";
    ship3.mobility = "Mobility=90";


    System.out.println("1  -"+ship1.name+"-      "+ship1.armour+"  "+ship1.attack+"  "+ship1.mobility);
    System.out.println("2  -"+ship2.name+"-  "+ship2.armour+"  "+ship2.attack+"  "+ship2.mobility);
    System.out.println("3  -"+ship3.name+"-      "+ship3.armour+"  "+ship3.attack+"  "+ship3.mobility);
    int chosen = Keyboard.readInt();

    switch (chosen) {
    case 1: 
        System.out.println("Heavy-type! Excellent choice! Great armour and guns! \n");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Medium-type! An all-rounder, a mix of everything! \n");
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("Light-type! Fast and mobile, but has little armour! \n");
        break;
    }


    System.out.println("Lets pimp out your ship! \n");

    String advancedHull = "1 - Advanced Hull Armour - Armour    +10";
    String betterAmmo = "2 - Better Ammo \t - Firepower +10";
    String booster = "3 - Booster \t\t - Mobility  +10";

    System.out.println(advancedHull+"\n"+betterAmmo+"\n"+booster);

}   
}
```

Comment: You already set the ship's armor when you first created it.  Why can't you do the same thing to change it?

Comment: I want it to be like a modification, to increase the armour or speed of firepower...

Comment: I don't understand why the question is downvoted, people should explain that when they do

Comment: You might want to add a constructor which sets armor, firepower and mobility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you the fields of the StarShip are all Strings, when you add two strings they are concatenated, eg `"abc"+"def" = "abcdef"` regardless of what they say. You want to use `int`s these are "java numbers" and add as you would expect eg `10 + 20 = 30`

```
class StarShip {     
    String name;
    int armour;
    int attack;      
    int mobility;
}

...

StarShip ship1 = new StarShip();
ship1.name = "Heavy-type";
ship1.armour = 90;
ship1.attack = 50;
ship1.mobility = 40;

...
```

When the user selects the ship we want to save this chose into a variable, like so:

```
Starship chosenShip; // must be declared outside the switch statement

switch (shipChoice ) {
case 1: 
    System.out.println("Heavy-type! Excellent choice! Great armour and guns! \n");
    chosenShip = ship1;
    Break;
...
```

Assuming `advancedHull` is selected and you include logic similar to how ships are selected

```
if (modificationChoice = 1){
    chosenShip.armour = chosenShip.armour + 10;
} ...
```

You may want to declare a `toSting()` methods in `StarShip` like so

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name +" Armour=" + armour +", Firepower=" + attack +", Mobility=" + mobility;
}
```

This way you can call `System.out.println(ship1.toString())` to print the ship info.

Example:

```
System.out.println(ship1.toString());
// outputs: Heavy-type Armour=90, Firepower=50, Mobility=40
ship1.armour += 10; // java shorthand for `ship1.armour + ship1.armour + 10`
System.out.println(ship1.toString());
// outputs: Heavy-type Armour=100, Firepower=50, Mobility=40
```

Comment: So if the user for example chose the heavy-type(like you showed) and added the modification hull armour, how would you write that?

Comment: And how did you assign "chosenShip" is that some method or something?

Comment: I have updated my answer i hope it answers your questions

Comment: That first bit, how you changed the switch, that's where I got stuck, thank you so much!!